# r geom_vline start from y=0

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this example

```
x<-rnorm(1000)
df<-data.frame(x)

library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(df,aes(x))+ 
geom_histogram(bins=10)+ 
ylim(-20, 300)+
geom_vline(xintercept=0)
```

How can I restrict my geom_vline to start from y=0 and not y = -20. Please note I dont want to change the range of `ylim`. I want my `ylim` to start from -20.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to switch to `annotate` with `geom="segment"`:

```r
x <- rnorm(1000)
df <- data.frame(x)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) +
  ylim(-20, 300) +
  annotate("segment", x = 0, xend = 0, y = 0, yend = Inf)
```

[image]